# If items with the same partition key exceeds 10GB, how would LSI works?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

AWS DynamoDB allows items with the same partition key exceeds 10GB (see [Is there a DynamoDB max partition size of 10GB for a single partition key value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272600/is-there-a-dynamodb-max-partition-size-of-10gb-for-a-single-partition-key-value))

But if I my schema has an LSI, what would happen? (See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html)

> For any local secondary index, you can store up to 10 GB of data per
>   distinct partition key value.

Not sure if this 10GB on LSI is a hard limit or DynamoDB has some internal mechanism to alleviate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a hard limit, with a documented error response if you exceed it.

First, a definion:

> In DynamoDB, an item collection is any group of items that have the same partition key value in a table and all of its local secondary indexes.

Now, the size restriction on an item collection:

> The maximum size of any item collection is 10 GB. This limit does not apply to tables without local secondary indexes; only tables that have one or more local secondary indexes are affected.
>
> If an item collection exceeds the 10 GB limit, DynamoDB will return an `ItemCollectionSizeLimitExceededException` and you won't be able to add more items to the item collection or increase the sizes of items that are in the item collection. (Read and write operations that shrink the size of the item collection are still allowed.)

Quotes are from the LSI docs in the DynamoDB Developer Guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.ItemCollections