# AWS DynamoDB LSI item collection size limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to understand what really AWS DynamoDB behaviour is.
When I create a Local Secondary Index (LSI) for the table, documentation says, that there is 10 GB limit for the item collection.
[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.ItemCollections.SizeLimit)

What does it really means?

Let's say my data is partitioned across 3 partitions, so questions are:

- each partition will have 10GB limit for LSI or in general across all partitions?
- If i reached a limit, let's say, I continue to write data to the table, that means that data will be in the table, but not seen by LSI? Or how? I understand it that in general data will be available in the table, but if I will query by LSI it will show me just old items, that we succeed to write before reached a limit, but if I will scan all table - I will see all items (old and new)? Right?

Will appreciate for any help
Thanks

**Possible answer:**

This post helped me to understand [If items with the same partition key exceeds 10GB, how would LSI works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105344/if-items-with-the-same-partition-key-exceeds-10gb-how-would-lsi-works)

It will raise exception in case we will reach a limit of 10GB for specific item collection(any group of items that have the same partition key value in a table and all of its local secondary indexes).

So if amount of items with specific partition key is not that big - you are save to use LSI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misreading the docs...

The Item Collection Size Limit applies to the table itself...

> The maximum size of any item collection is 10 GB. This limit **does not**
> **apply to tables without local secondary indexes**. Only tables that have
> one or more local secondary indexes are affected.

So if you have a table with an LSI, then you can not have more than 10GB for any given partition key in the table.

If you have lots of data, paying to have a GSI with the same partition key as the table but a different sort key instead of a free LSI if needed is a solution.

Comment: To put a finer point on the last statement, if you don't need the strong consistency of an LSI, go with a GSI. More flexibility, more options, fewer limitations.

Comment: Thanks for explanation