# DynamoDB Partitioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

A partition can max store 10gb of data. Dynamodb Identifies the data location by passing the partition key to a hash function. Now if for a particular partition key's total data crosses 10GB what will happen? I understand that if total size of a partition is greater than 10GB new partitions are allocated and data is split. My question is what if the item collection of a particular partition key is greater than 10GB, how is that handled ? If new partition is added in such scenario the hashing concept fails right, because a hash can have only one output. Please help me understand this concept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a DynamoDB max partition size of 10GB for a single partition key value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272600/is-there-a-dynamodb-max-partition-size-of-10gb-for-a-single-partition-key-value)