# Is there any size limit for DynamoDB global secondary index with low cardinality partition key?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB GSI with a low cardinality (1) partition key and a sort key. I'm not able to find any information about any limits for this partition key. I already read how it's supposed to behave in case of primary key with a low cardinality as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272600/is-there-a-dynamodb-max-partition-size-of-10gb-for-a-single-partition-key-value), but I'm not sure if the same principles apply for global secondary indexes.

My main concern is: Can I fetch the items properly sorted by the sort key no matter how much the index grows? Or I need to resort to write-sharding as described [here](https://www.dynamodbguide.com/leaderboard-write-sharding/)?

Any help or a pointer to the documentation describing the behavior will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How much data are we talking, what capacity mode is the table in, and how much write traffic is the base table getting at any given time?

Comment: @Kirk, The capacity mode is on-demand, and the expected traffic is in several thousand items per day.